# jquery dropdown selected values

Tags: jquery, html, json, drop-down-menu

I have a group of sequential drop downs that populate depending on selections from the previous drop down. Now once the third drop down has a chosen value, `<option>` by the user, that value is added to the table below it.

What I am trying to work out is, how can i make it so if `choice 3` has the value `unsure` selected by the user, after this, if the user then selects for `choice 1`, `unsure` as well, `unsure` will be removed from `choice 3`? So the latest selection will override any other `choice`'s with the same value entered into the table. The table cannot have any two of the same values entered into it.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  <select  name='first' id='first'>
    <option selected="selected" value="nothing">choose</option>   
    <option value='opt_a'>opt a</option>
  </select>
  <select name='sec' id='sec'>
  </select>
  <select name='third' id='third'>
  </select>
   <br />
   <br />
 <div id="result">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>category</td>
      <th>choice</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
      <td>choice 1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>choice 2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>choice 3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>choice 4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
data = {
opt_a: ['choose_1','choose_2','choose_3','choose_4'],
choose_1: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_2: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_3: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure'],
choose_4: ['yes','no','unsure','still unsure']
}

$('#first').change(function(){
var firstopts = ''
$.each(data[$(this).val()],function(i,v){
  firstopts += "<option value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</option>"
}) 
$('#sec').html(firstopts)
})


$('#sec').change(function(){
var secopts = ''
$.each(data[$(this).val()],function(i,v){
  secopts += "<option value='"+v+"'>"+v+"</option>"
}) 
$('#third').html(secopts)
})

$('#third').change(function() {
  $('table tr').filter(function() {
    var number1 = $('#sec').val().split('_')[1];
    var number2 = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().split(' ')[1];
    return number1 == number2;
  }).find('td:eq(1)').text($(this).val());
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for last select element

```
  $('#third').change(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function(index){
       var tdVal=$.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html());
       if(tdVal==$('#third').val())
        $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html('');
    });
      $('table tr').filter(function() {
        var number1 = $('#sec').val().split('_')[1];
        var number2 = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().split(' ')[1];
        return number1 == number2;
      }).find('td:eq(1)').text($(this).val());
    });
```

Try out from here http://jsfiddle.net/qQaRC/1/

Answer (score 1):

First create div's into the  elements where the users selection is shown and give the div's an id.

Then try to create an array:

```
mychoices = new Array();
```

Every time a change is done to a selectbox by the user you have to check if the choice is already in the array. If the choice still is not found in the array, create a pair of key-value. If it already exists override it.

```
if(!(choice in mychoices)){
   mychoices[choice] = <div id from the table>;
   /* write the value into the div of the table */
   ...
}
else{
   /* get the id of the div where the choice is in */
   id_value = mychoices[choice];
   /* write the value into the div of the table. use the id you have in variable 
      id_value */
   ...
}
```

Variable choice contains your values you would like to check (yes,no, unsure,...). You have to determine the option your user clicked onto.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I decided to use Khanal Kamal's answer, as it fits my script and functionality. I didn't want to generate `<div>`'s into my code as well as new arrays.

Comment: I found a little "bug" in your script. When I choose the first option (in your code "yes") the table is not updated because it is not a change. I would like to recommend to create an unselectable entry "--- please select ---" or to initialize your table with "yes". Hope it is clear what I mean...

Comment: Ah Yes. Well spotted. Thank You for the advice. I will fix it up.